# Command line number manipulation on a continuous serial data stream

Tags: bash, serial-port, numbers

I run the following in the command line:

`prog1 | prog2`

The output (say, **X**) of above is a 4-digit hex number, e.g. FA34.
`prog1` is a java program which reads data every 100ms on the serial. `prog2` is the `cut` command which cuts out a portion I need. This works fine and I can see the desired value every 100ms on the standard out.

What I want:

`prog1 | prog2 | <convert X to decimal> | <multiply by 2>`

How to do this, using pipes or not, **in the command line in one-go**?

*Note: I wrote a bash script to convert X to decimal and multiply by 2. But I couldn't direct X into my script as an argument.*

Comment: 1. there is a standard tool for that - `xargs`: `prog1 | prog2 | xargs echo "ibase=16;obase=A;2*" | bc` (or something like that) 2. you can read that number from the stdin in your bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a funny possibility:

```
{ echo "iscale=16"; prog1 | prog2; } | sed 's/$/*2/' | bc
```

This echos `iscale=16` first (to tell `bc` to consider user's input in radix 16). Then `sed` appends `*2` to each line and all this goes through bc for the conversion to decimal and multiplication by 2.

There's a limitation: your program `prog2` must output all the hexadecimal numbers in upper case (e.g., `FA34` not `fa34`). If this is a limitation, use:

```
{ echo "iscale=16"; prog1 | prog2; } | sed 's/\(.*\)/\U\1*2/g' | bc
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
prog1 | prog2 | xargs -I ^ printf "%d * 2\n" 0x^ | bc
```

Explanation:

print with %d converts it to decimal, bc does the multiplication

Comment: It gives no error, but I can't see anything on standard out (I mean the screen).

Comment: do you see output from prog1 | prog2 ?
If so can you post the output?

Comment: `echo "FA34\nAAAA\nBABA\nBABE\n" | xargs -I ^ printf "%d * 2\n" 0x^ | bc`

The expectation is each hex number is in new line. I have tested the above code  in bash,zsh

Comment: @imp25 @choroba

my `prog1 | prog2` is `java net.tinyos.tools.Listen | cut -c49-50,52-53`. the output looks like:

serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:115200: resynchronising
0FFF
0FFF
0FFF
serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:115200: bad packet
0FFF
0FFF
0FFF
0FFF
0FFF
.
.

it goes on...0FFF is just a dummy value.

Comment: thanks, solution works. ut, i found an alternative solution with gnuplot replot to avoid time lag i experienced.

Answer (score 1):

This reads the output of prog2 to a variable v, then converts it to decimal (using the base notation `16#v`) and multiplies by two.

```
prog1 | prog2 | ( read v ; let v=16#$v*2 ; echo $v )
```

If the stream contains more than one number, change the last part to

```
( while read v ; do let v=16#$v*2 ; echo $v ; done )
```

Comment: It gives no error, but I can't see anything on standard out (I mean the screen).

Comment: @mlomailom: Try `echo FA34 | { read v ; let v=16#$v*2 ; echo $v ; }`. If it works, there is something wrong with the output of prog2.

Comment: it works. hmm...here's my prog1 and prog2: java net.tinyos.tools.Listen | cut -c49-50,52-53 that gives me hex values like FA23 every 100ms. any thoughts?

Comment: @mlomailom: Updated the answer for endless streams.

Comment: it works. but the result doesn't come in real time. it hangs for 1 - 2 mins, then i see the correct result (100s of lines). then it stops again for 1 - 2 mins. then it starts again. any idea why this behavior?

Comment: prog1 | prog1 | (while read v; do let v=16#$v*2 ; echo $v ; done)

Comment: thanks, solution works. but, i found an alternative solution with gnuplot replot to avoid time lag i experienced.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in a pipe you can use `perl`:

```
    prog1 | prog2 | perl -ne 'printf ("%d\n",(hex "$_")*2);'
```

This loops over the lines of ouptut from prog2 (-n option) and reformats from hex (`hex "$_"`) and multiplies by 2 before outputting as decimal.

**Edit**

You may need to clear the stdout buffer, in perl you can do this with '$|++':

```
 prog1 | prog2 | perl -e '$|++; while(<STDIN>) { chomp; printf ("%d\n",(hex "$_")*2); }'
```

Comment: It gives no error, but I can't see anything on standard out (I mean the screen). Same like for the other 2 answers I got.  Not sure why!

Comment: Strange. What happens when you just try and print the standard input, without any formatting? i.e. `perl -ne 'print "$_\n";`

Comment: You may need to flush stdout to that it updates before the pipe has finished. I'll add an edit as an example.

Comment: something happened. result below:

`$ java net.tinyos.tools.Listen | cut -c49-50,52-53 | perl -e '$|++; while(<STDIN>) { chomp; printf ("%d\n",(hex "$_")*2); }'`

**result**
serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:115200: resynchronising
serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:115200: bad packet
serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:115200: ignoring unknown packet type 0x0
serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:115200: bad packet
serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:115200: bad packet
. <takes a minute or two to start from here, conversion is correct>
.
.
8190
8190
8190
8190
8190
8190
.
.<stops after some 100s of lines>
.
8190 <starts again>

this continues.

Comment: thanks, solution works. but, i found an alternative solution with gnuplot replot to avoid time lag i experienced.